# Six foot tall, a herd of elephant: special use of the singular in certain syntactic contexts

Tags: grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis, irregular-plurals

CambridgeGEL, page 1588 reads

> Examples like *She’s six foot tall* involve a special use of the
> singular form rather than a base plural: the difference between this
> and *How many feet are there in a mile?* is a matter of syntax rather
> than of inflectional morphology.
>
> In *a herd of **elephant*** it is arguable  that the construction
> involves not a base plural, but a special use of the singular in
> certain syntactic contexts (comparable to the *six **foot** tall*
> construction).

What are that "special use" and those "syntactic contexts" the author refers to?

Comment: The authors are saying that this arguably _exemplifies_ "a special use of 'the singular' which is also (perhaps the 'arguably' extends to these also) seen in other contexts".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _Examples like **She’s six foot tall** involve a special use of the singular form rather than a base plural: the difference between this and **How many feet are there in a mile?** is a matter of syntax rather than of inflectional morphology._

Comment: Why do you ask questions here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth where here? what questons?

Answer (score 0):

MIDDLE ENGLISH *fot* /foːt/ "foot" : by far the most common plural form is *feet*, and **fot** is usually only used in contexts of the unit of length.

OED: *Foot* (pl. *feet*): lineal measure (Often in sing. when after numerals).  2. Ellipt. *Foot-soldiers*; †men of foot. Often after an ordinal, with ‘regiment of’ omitted.

Comment: Not my downvote above, by the way. Here, I think you're playing off one venerable authority against another. And if I was going to challenge CGEL on matters of interpretation like this, I'd want more than the views of even the best lexicographers to support my criticisms. Top grammarians look at developments in syntax _and_ semantics.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In front of another noun, the plural for the unit of length is _foot_: _a 20-foot putt; his 70-foot ketch_. **Foot** can also be used instead of _feet_ when mentioning a quantity and in front of words like _tall: four foot of snow; he is at least six foot tall_ https://www.wordreference.com/definition/foot

Answer (score -1):

"Six foot" should be hyphenated ("six-foot") because it constitutes as single adjectival phrase.  For the same reason, "foot" is in the singular.  For example, "a six-foot soldier."

"Six feet" would be used (in the plural and without a hyphen) where "feet" is a noun within the sentence, and not part of an adjectival phrase: for example, "the soldier's head was six feet above the ground."